# Qt Quick program lag when play video on Ubuntu14.04

Tags: qt, qml, mp4

I use Qt 5.4.2, and i created a Qt Quick program for play video.

My video spec. is 1920x1080, H.264, 25f/s, 12502kbps

code is copy from simply video example

```
        VideoOutput {
        anchors.fill: parent;
        source: mediaPlayer;

        signal sizeChanged;
        signal fatalError;

        property alias duration: mediaPlayer.duration;
        property alias mediaSource: mediaPlayer.source;
        property alias metaData: mediaPlayer.metaData;
        property alias playbackRate: mediaPlayer.playbackRate;
        property alias position: mediaPlayer.position;
        property alias volume: mediaPlayer.volume;

        MediaPlayer {
            id: mediaPlayer;
            autoLoad: true;
            autoPlay: true;
            source: "file:///" + applicationDirPath + "/video/" + playVideoList.currItem();

            onError: {
                if (MediaPlayer.NoError != error) {
                    console.log("[qmlvideo] VideoItem.onError error " + error + " errorString " + errorString);
                    console.log(mediaPlayer.source)
                }
            }

            onStopped: {
                mediaPlayer.source = "file:///" + applicationDirPath + "/video/" + playVideoList.nextItem();
                mediaPlayer.play();
            }
        }
        onHeightChanged: sizeChanged();
        function start() { mediaPlayer.play(); }
        function stop() { mediaPlayer.stop(); }
    }
```

This program is always being lag when it play video.

Is there any suggest?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally i know that is MediaPlayer of Qt too weak to play high quality video.

Now i use 3rd party module QtAV