# Video glitches and not smooth (qt)

Tags: qt, video, qml

I'm attempting to play a video using the Video component in QML, but I'm facing issues with the video playback. The playback is not smooth, and there are occasional glitches. The video has a resolution of 4080x720.

What can I do to improve the video performance?

Note that i'm using qt5.14, Windows 10.

Here's my current approach:

```
Video {
    id: idMediaPlayer
    anchors.fill: parent
    source: "test.mp4"
    fillMode: VideoOutput.PreserveAspectCrop
    muted: true
}
```

Comment: Possibly related/duplicates: [Terrible performance with QMediaPlayer and QVideoWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759695/terrible-performance-with-qmediaplayer-and-qvideowidget), [Qt Quick program lag when play video on Ubuntu14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41057397/qt-quick-program-lag-when-play-video-on-ubuntu14-04)

Comment: 5.14 is very old, start by upgrading to 5.15.x and see if that works any better (or move to Qt 6 as 5 series is soon out of support)